# Stuck on an alternating sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Hi I'm currently doing some exercise problems for my first year university math course. The formula I'm supposed to proof is the following:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1} 
$$

I tried using induction, and while the start is easy, I'm not able to proof the implication from $n$ to $n+1$. Using the pattern we learned for those kinds of questions I'd get

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\binom{n+1}{k} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+2}\binom{n+1}{k}
$$

The main trouble with that is the $n+1$ in the binomial coefficient where I don't see a way to do induction.

I also thought about multiplying the sum with $n+1$, in the hope that stuff in the sum would cancel out, leaving me with a $1$ at the end, but I didn't progress that way either.

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could hint me at what I'm missing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use $\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Use
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{k+1} = \int_0 ^1 x^k dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now should the sum start at $k=0$ ? ... then we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} \binom{n}{k} &=& \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-x)^k  dx \\ 
&=& \int_0^1 (1-x)^n dx = \frac{1}{n+1}. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}